# Fill a field on sheet 1 with a value from sheet 2 based on a value in sheet 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with

- a table of documents on the tab "Documents"
- a table of review cycles for the documents on the tab "ReviewList"

The order of the documents on the ReviewList sheet is not (and never will be) the same as the order on the Documents sheet, so I can't do a straight incrementation.

I have a "doctype" field on the Documents sheet that I want to appear on the ReviewList sheet.

Currently the "ReviewList" sheet has a 'DocName' column, whose value is a reference to the 'DocName' column on the "Documents" sheet (Ex. =Documents!D27).

**What I want** is to have a 'doctype' column on the "ReviewList" sheet that matches the correct doctype from the "Documents" sheet.

So for example, if the value for ReviewList:$A4 is "=Documents!D27", then I want the value for ReviewList:$E4 (the 'doctype' column) to have the correct value from Documents!$O27.

Obviously I can do this manually, but I'd rather have a formula. I have tried several different ways including VLOOKUP and MATCH, but can't seem to get this to work correctly.

Comment: You might want to give us an example of a filename and the value you would expect as 'doctype'. Do you mean something like `filename.pdf` with doctype `pdf`?

Comment: Sure: Doc name: "Command Reference"   Doctype: Reference

Comment: Doc name: "Xeno Blade Installation Guide"   Doctype: Installation

Comment: Doc name: Xeno Licence Guide  Doctype: Reference

Comment: Only thing I can make of this is that you probably can define specific keywords in the filename that specify the doctype. I'd recommend to look into [this formula that shows how to check if a cell contains a specific text](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text) and [the ifs formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45)

Comment: Thanks Casper. The 'DocName' value is *not* a filename, and so there is not a unique value to be referenced. What I'm trying to avoid is manually updating the reference fields every time I change the list of documents.